# What does the Jewel Crown do?

Tags: wizorb

The game is quite cryptic about the actual effects of the Jewel crown, **what happens if you buy it?**

[image: Jewel Crown screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Youtube video below, it triggers a "bad" ending to the game, but also unlocks the "My Precioussss" achievement.